# Column UID missing in custom TYPO3 v10 extension

Tags: mysql, sql, typo3, typo3-10.x

While updating my TYPO3 project from v7 to v10, I encountered some difficulties with my custom extensions.
Due to that I just tried to rebuild the demo extension from the official TYPO3 website: **https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/4-FirstExtension/2-create-folder-structure-and-configuration-files.html** to see what has changed over the years.
I followed the instruction as stated on the website.

After successfully activating the extension, I browsed to the list view but I get the following error:

> Unknown column 'uid' in 'field list'
> [link to error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzkHk.png)

I checked my database and the column 'uid' really is missing, column 'pid' exists.

This is my ext_tables.sql:

```
    uid int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL auto_increment,
    pid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

    name varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    quantity int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (uid),
    KEY parent (pid)
);
```

On my second attempt I copied the entire project from **https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation-Examples/store_inventory** but still encounter the same error.

Do you have an idea what I have to change, to not receive that error anymore?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dropping the database table and creating it newly it worked.

Comment: What do you mean by resetting the database table.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem, but can't remember what was the reason.

When I had the problem, there may have been other copies of the same extension (same extension key) in typo3conf/ext. This may cause problems (even if these extensions are not enabled).

Apart from that, could it be a simple cache problem or database compare problem?

You should be fine, if you created the extension and then activated it. But if changes were made, you may have to clear the system cache. In any case, the TCA is cached, so if you make changes there, the system cache should get cleared.

If you use https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation-Examples/store_inventory directly, that extension is for 8.7 and has not been updated. I currently can't guarantee it will work for 10.